# LCD Arduino not displaying correctly

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

My problem is when I input the string in the serial monitor it shows like this:

[LCD Arduino Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA1J1.jpg)
 The setCursor dont work and also there is another weird character created before the actual output.

This is my sample code:

```cpp
void setup() {

    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {

    String readString;
    String Q;
    while (Serial.available()) {
        delay(1);
        if (Serial.available()>0) {
            char c = Serial.read();
            if(isControl(c)){
                break;
            }
            readString += c;
        }
    }
    Q = readString;
    if (Q == "1"){
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("Hello");
    }
    if (Q == "2"){
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should understand the LCD lib functions.
 To set the cursorto theFirst row you need

```
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);  // row index starts with 0
```

if you only set the cursor back without clearing the screen there might be weird chars,sodo a

```
 lcd.clear(); //clears the whole screen
```

OR define an empty String:

```
 String lineClear ="                ";  // should be 16 spaces for a 16x2 display
```

and do as a clearing sequence (e.g. for the top line)

```
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print(lineClear);
 lcd.print("Hello");
```

Remember the syntax is

```
 lcd.setCursor(col, row)  
 // index for 16x2 is col 0-15,row 0-1 
 // index for 20x4 is col 0-19,row 0-3
```

and in setup alwas do a

```
lcd.clear();
```

after initializing the lcd, to remove possible artefacts from the buffer

Comment: Thank you Codebreaker007. I found that the problem all along is incorrect placing of wires from lcd to arduino.I already fix the correct placement and it works.